# What information do I need to configure to connect to the other party's Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I saw keystore and truststore certificates on the Internet.Some say one of the two. Some say they need both.

In my business, I need to support SSL and PLAIN modes.

The basis for distinguishing which mode to use is whether the security.protocol field in the incoming JSON is SASL_SSL or SASL_PLAIN.

```java
        Properties pro = new Properties();

        String sasl = String.format("org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"%s\"  password=\"%s\";", userName, password);
        pro.setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", sasl);
        pro.setProperty("ssl.cipher.suites", suites);   
        pro.setProperty("ssl.enabled.protocols", authorizedEncryptionMode);
        pro.setProperty("security.protocol", protocols);    
        pro.setProperty("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        pro.setProperty("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        for (String ipAndPort : ipAndPorts) {
            pro.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", ipAndPort);
            try(Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(pro)) {
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, null, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        alarmModel.getString("alarmId"), new Record(alarmModel).toString()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.info("pmRuleDeliverBySouthKafka failed....", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe this problem is relatively low-level. Maybe someone can tell me where the article can solve my doubts?

Comment: I need your help, please.

Comment: The "other party" should be able to provide this information. There's no single answer other than to say that obviously the bootstrap server is a required property and the rest depend on not just the SSL or JAAS configs, but also the server side `authorizer.class.name`. You also multiple bootstrap addresses to support SSL and (SASL_)PLAINTEXT